# Unable to run groovy scripts with latest jenkins version

Tags: jenkins, groovy, chef-infra

I am in the process of upgrading jenkins server to latest LTS version (2.204.2 to 2.251.2) in my current work environment.
In present scenario jenkins installation and configuration is an automated process via chef.

The problem starts here :

- i need to upgrade my jenkins server to latest LTS version via chef cookbook
- remoting option has been obsolete in latest jenkins version
- my present cookbook uses jenkins_script resource (using jenkins 6.0 cookbook from supermarket) to run groovy scripts
- i am able to upgrade my jenkins server but unable to execute groovy scripts via jenkins-cli, its picking remoting option all the time and failing even though its obsolete in latest version
- Is there any automated way to change protocol from remoting to ssh/http when chef client runs
  .

Any valuable inputs will be helpful

Comment: Typo ? Upgrade to ..  LTS version (2.251.2 -> 2.204.2)  ?

Comment: @IanW yes i want to upgrade to stable Jenkins version

Comment: 2.251.2 is greater than your target (latest LTS) and does not exist. What is your starting point? Assume it is 1.251.2. have considered creating a new 2.x environment and migrating jobs into it? There are lots of security settings tightened in recent 2.x releases (in tbe last year esp.) which could be  pose in-situ hurdles.

Comment: @IanW, my bad, its from 2.204.2v to 2.251.2v

Comment: 2.204.2 IS the latest LTS. 2.221 is the latest weekly. You can't upgrade to 2.251.2 probably for another 40± weeks when it might finally come out.